# update primary key to a new one in sql server

Tags: sql-server, database-design, update, primary-key, date

I have got a table that has four columns and the Id is a Primary key:

| Id | Matricule | Date | Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `G00183|2022-04-30|30` | G00183 | 2022-04-30 00:00:00.000 | 30 |
| `G00183|2022-04-30|5010` | G00183 | 2022-04-30 00:00:00.000 | 5010 |
| `G00183|2022-04-30|5070` | G00183 | 2022-04-30 00:00:00.000 | 5070 |

And for some reason, the Id field change its format of insertion

- From `Matricule|Date|Code`  (date in yyyy-mm-dd format and Pipeline as separator)
- To `Matricule_Date_Code`    (date in dd/mm/yy format and underscore as separator)

| Id | Matricule | Date | Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `G00183_30/04/22_30` | G00183 | 2022-04-30 00:00:00.000 | 30 |
| `G00183_30/04/22_5010` | G00183 | 2022-04-30 00:00:00.000 | 5010 |
| `G00183_30/04/22_5070` | G00183 | 2022-04-30 00:00:00.000 | 5070 |

And I want to modify old rows that have old format of Id to the new one:
But the questions came to my mind, and hope someone clarifies them for me!

- I think the design of this table is bad because the primary key of the table would be a combination of three columns, instead of just one, and its value is concatenated with three fields!

I could fix with this Query:

```sql
UPDATE Elements
set Id = concat(Matricule,'_', convert(varchar, Date, 3),'_',Code)
```

I tried to do it with `REPLACE` but I don't know how can I do it with regex?

```sql
UPDATE Elements
set Id = REPLACE(Id, '|', '_')
```

Comment: Why do you think you need regex?...your `REPLACE()` code is correct as is. Also yes, your primary key should be normalized into 3 separate fields. It's ok if you make it a composite primary key of those 3 fields, but stuffing 3 pieces of data into 1 field is bad design.

Comment: Is your PK column referenced by anything? Do other columns have foreign key references pointing at that column ( including any references that aren't enforced by constraints)? Updating values in a column is one thing, even refactoring into multiple columns, but when keys are involved, it can get much more complicated.